Migrate from Infopath to PowerApps (Tool)
I have a development in Infopath that I need to migrate to PowerApps. Do you know if there is any tool that allows me to do direct migration from Infopath to PowerApps? or is it necessary to start development in Power Apps from zero?
Thank you all and regards.

There is no tool that automatically converts InfoPath forms to Canvas Apps.
You would need to start from scratch, unfortunately.
